# three.js Line disappears on updating the vertices of its geometry

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am learning three.js library in JS. I used the Line objects to create my own coordinate axes. I am trying to move them. The problem is when I update the vertices, two of the lines work fine, but the third line disappears completely. I tried printing its vertices on console but they are within visibility range. So, what is the reason I am facing this problem? My code:

```
// create and axes to the scene
    //// X axis
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x00ff00
    })
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(1500,0,0), new THREE.Vector3(-1500,0,0));
    Xaxis = new THREE.Line(geometry,material);
    scene.add(Xaxis);

    //// Y axis
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000
    })
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,1500,0), new THREE.Vector3(0,-1500,0));
    Yaxis = new THREE.Line(geometry,material);
    scene.add(Yaxis);

    //// Z axis
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x0000ff
    })
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1500), new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1500));
    Zaxis = new THREE.Line(geometry,material);
    scene.add(Zaxis);

function changePosition(newVal)
{
    if(!transformCo_ordinate) {
        sphere.position.set((vx/100)*newVal,(vy/100)*newVal,(vz/100)*newVal);
    }
    else{
        Xaxis.geometry.vertices[0].set(1500,-(vy/100)*newVal,-(vz/100)*newVal);
        Xaxis.geometry.vertices[1].set(-1500,-(vy/100)*newVal,-(vz/100)*newVal);

        Yaxis.geometry.vertices[0].set(-(vx/100)*newVal,1500,-(vz/100)*newVal);
        Yaxis.geometry.vertices[1].set(-(vx/100)*newVal,-1500,-(vz/100)*newVal);

        Zaxis.geometry.vertices[0].set(-(vx/100)*newVal,-(vy/100)*newVal,1500);
        Zaxis.geometry.vertices[0].set(-(vx/100)*newVal,-(vy/100)*newVal,-1500);

        Xaxis.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
        Yaxis.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
        Zaxis.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
        console.log(Xaxis.geometry.vertices[1]);
    }

}
```

THe function `changePosition` is being called by a slider which passes its current value as `newVal` within range 0-100. `vx = 100, vy = 100, vz = -300`

Xaxis is the line that disappears. `transformCo_ordinate` is a boolean controlled by a checkbox. I am new to three.js so please understand if I am doing some stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Zaxis.geometry.vertices[0].set(-(vx/100)*newVal,-(vy/100)*newVal,1500);
Zaxis.geometry.vertices[0].set(-(vx/100)*newVal,-(vy/100)*newVal,-1500);
```

It seems you are updating the same vertex of the z axis twice. I've ported a simplified version of your code into the following fiddle. After fixing this minor bug, everything seems to work fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/gcL7dwbp/

The axis are automatically updated two seconds after application start.

`three.js R104`

Comment: Thanks. that was it. that was really a silly mistake.